# How to initialize a variable with javascript in ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to implement a great theme to a rails 4 app for learning purposes. The theme located here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/09/25/3d-restaurant-menu-concept/

I distributed the .css and .js in their respective directories.

```
vendor/assets/stylesheets/

vendor/assets/javascripts/
```

I added the new files in the assets pipeline for the app to load them

CSS

```
app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

*= require style
*= require normalize
*= require demo
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
```

Javascript files are loading, I can see it on the header of the page source.

Here is the javascript file:

```
var Menu = (function() {

var $container = $( '#rm-container' ),                      
    $cover = $container.find( 'div.rm-cover' ),
    $middle = $container.find( 'div.rm-middle' ),
    $right = $container.find( 'div.rm-right' ),
    $open = $cover.find('a.rm-button-open'),
    $close = $right.find('span.rm-close'),
    $details = $container.find( 'a.rm-viewdetails' ),

    init = function() {

        initEvents();

    },
    initEvents = function() {

        $open.on( 'click', function( event ) {

            openMenu();
            return false;

        } );

        $close.on( 'click', function( event ) {

            closeMenu();
            return false;

        } );

        $details.on( 'click', function( event ) {

            $container.removeClass( 'rm-in' ).children( 'div.rm-modal' ).remove();
            viewDetails( $( this ) );
            return false;

        } );

    },
    openMenu = function() {

        $container.addClass( 'rm-open' );

    },
    closeMenu = function() {

        $container.removeClass( 'rm-open rm-nodelay rm-in' );

    },
    viewDetails = function( recipe ) {

        var title = recipe.text(),
            img = recipe.data( 'thumb' ),
            description = recipe.parent().next().text(),
            url = recipe.attr( 'href' );

        var $modal = $( '<div class="rm-modal"><div class="rm-thumb" style="background-image: url(' + img + ')"></div><h5>' + title + '</h5><p>' + description + '</p><a href="' + url + '">See the recipe</a><span class="rm-close-modal">x</span></div>' );

        $modal.appendTo( $container );

        var h = $modal.outerHeight( true );
        $modal.css( 'margin-top', -h / 2 );

        setTimeout( function() {

            $container.addClass( 'rm-in rm-nodelay' );

            $modal.find( 'span.rm-close-modal' ).on( 'click', function() {

                $container.removeClass( 'rm-in' );

            } );

        }, 0 );

    };

return { init : init };
})();
```

There is a script in the html file I need to run but I have not been able to implement it to rails 4.2.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            Menu.init();

        });
    </script>
```

I ve tried to leave the script in the .html.erb file but it does not work, I also tried to add the script to a javascript file in 
    app/assets/javascripts/controller.js
but is does not work either.

This works if I click on the html file of the template in my computer, but how can I implement it on rails?

Comment: @the_call_me_joe please check your application.js file, I think your js is not included inside that.

Comment: @Arv I m sorry I forgot to include it in the question.
All .js files have been added to application.js. Thank you.

Comment: @the_call_me_joe I just integrated the theme,  I  found we have to add js in bottom,  not in top as we got in default. You can find a code here https://github.com/arvindvyas/3dtheme

Comment: @Avr Thank you so much!! you don t know how long I have been trying to get this working! you made my day! I don t really know what happened with my source code.

Comment: @Arv how did you manage to block the controller views and just leave the layout to render things?

Comment: I did not get you, I just create an app for demo.

Comment: @Arv sorry, I was debugging the code. How did you know that you had to move the javascripts block bellow the <%= yield %> part of the  view?

Comment: it was mention in the index file of that theme

Comment: @Arv please leave your first comment as an answer so I can select it :)

Comment: @they-call-me-joe added that please check :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to not inclusion of `js` file in proper place inside `application.js` , i reviewed the `index.html` file of the `theme` and found `js` file should be in bottom.
         You can find the more details [here](https://github.com/arvindvyas/3dtheme)

Answer (score 0):

For this you could use this in your view file

```
<script>
$.getScript('/path to file', function(){

    $(document).ready(menu);
    $(document).on('page:load', menu);

});
</script>
```

If the document is loaded the Menu function will be executed.

Its is possible that the `$.getScript()` can't find the function, there for you will need to put the js file in the views map of the specific controller.

Don't forget to add a route in the `config/routes.rb`

And change `var Menu = (function() {` into `menu = function() {` and place `var menu;` in the top of the js file.